# java jdbc gui application - need to allow user input

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, jdbc, insert

I need to create a Java JDBC GUI application for a manager to be able to enter in data for an employee regarding their dependents. My code is below and everything works fine. I just can't figure out how to allow a user to be able to enter in data for more than one dependent. Thinking I'll need a loop of some sort but can't figure out how to add that to this code. Everything I've tried hasn't worked so far, only the most recent entered values get inserted into the database.

```
  package database;

  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class addDependent {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    getConnection();
    addEmplDependent();

     }

    public static void addEmplDependent() throws Exception{

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Employee SSN: ");
    String ESSN = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter Dependent Name: ");
    String DNAME = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter Sex: ");
    String SEX = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter Relationship: ");
    String RELATIONSHIP  = scanner.nextLine();



    String insertSQL3 = "INSERT INTO DEPENDENT"
            + "(ESSN,DEPENDENT_NAME,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?,?)";


    scanner.close();

    try {
        dbConnection = getConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertSQL3);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, ESSN);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, DNAME);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, SEX);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, RELATIONSHIP);

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        }
    catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    finally {
        System.out.println("Insert Completed!");
        }

    }



    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
    try {
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@apollo.vse.gmu.edu:1521:ite10g";
        String username = "*******";
        String password = "******";
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, 
    password);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        return conn;
    } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    return null; 
      }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a swing-GUI and insert data on clicking a button.
If you want to run it on the command line, just loop on every row to insert until the user decides to quit. Changing your code as few as possible, it could look somehow like this:

```
public class addDependent {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
  addEmplDependent();
}

public static void addEmplDependent() throws Exception{

  Connection dbConnection = null;
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
  String insertSQL3 = "INSERT INTO DEPENDENT "
        + "(ESSN,DEPENDENT_NAME,SEX,RELATIONSHIP) VALUES "
        + "(?,?,?,?)";

  try {
    dbConnection = getConnection();
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertSQL3);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean continue = true;
    while ( continue ) {
        System.out.print("Enter Employee SSN: ");
        String ESSN = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Dependent Name: ");
        String DNAME = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Sex: ");
        String SEX = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Relationship: ");
        String RELATIONSHIP  = scanner.nextLine();

            preparedStatement.setString(1, ESSN);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, DNAME);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, SEX);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, RELATIONSHIP

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.print("Continue ? (y/n) : ");
        String goaHead  = scanner.nextLine();
        if ( goaHead.equalsIgnoreCase("n") {
          continue = false;
        }

    }
    scanner.close();
    dbConnection.close();
    preparedStatement.close();

}
catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
finally {
    System.out.println("Insert Completed!");        

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks Fredy ! I actually did end up going with using swing instead. I'll have to see if I can implement your additions to my swing-gui to allow a user to enter in data for more than one dependent. appreciate your help!